# Maintaining Form Data With Redirect

Tags: php, forms, post

I have to send variable value catch from my form input.

The code is this one

```
<?php
  if( isset($_POST['btn']) ) {  
  $surname = $_POST["surname"];
  header("location: page2.php");
}

?>

<form id="frm" name="frm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" >
<input name="surname" type="text"> 
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="btn">continue</button>

</form>
```

When I get redirected to `page2.php` and I call `$_POST["surname"]` it doesn't work, nothing is displayed.

Any help on this?

Comment: The question is how to send form data with a redirect? Why not submit the form to `page2.php` directly? Setting `$surname` isn't doing anything.

Comment: Does surname have any value?

Comment: I think I've rephrased the question to what you are trying to ask. Please edit if that is incorrect. "going to page2.php" wasn't clear. If you were loading that in the browser directly that wouldn't have a POST. Presuming you meant redirected based on `header("location: page2.php");`.

Comment: By default, a `header("location: ...)` sets a `302` status code, and browsers follow that, by making a _GET_ request for the new URL - so of course you have no POST data available there any more. You could explicitly specify the status code `307` - then clients are supposed to _keep_ the original request method, and send all the data again. (That might be okay in a case of so little data as here - if you had f.e. a form that included a file upload, this would be less advisable, because the client has to send all the data _twice_.)

Comment: Of course you could also put the value into the query string of the URL you are redirecting to (so that you can receive it via $_GET then), or put it into a session.

Comment: why instead of a redirect you do a include of what you want to do in page2? your logic does not make sense to me.

Comment: As above... POST or GET data only exists for the lifetime of the request in which it was actually sent. A redirect causes a new request, so the data won't exist in that request (barring caveats about things like 307 redirects - which requires the browser to actually honour that, of course). This is the basic mechanics of HTTP - you need to make sure you understand how the web works, if you want to build web applications.